# Error: 'AppRoutingModule' module can't import itself

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am following angular documentation on routing: https://angular.io/guide/router
I am at end of milestone 2: routing module.

This is my angular-router-sample\src\app\app-routing.module.ts:

```
                import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
            import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

            import { CrisisListComponent } from './crisis-list/crisis-list.component';
            import { HeroListComponent } from './hero-list/hero-list.component';
            import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';



            const appRoutes: Routes = [
              { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
              { path: 'heroes', component: HeroListComponent },
              { path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
              { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
            ];

            @NgModule({
              declarations: [],
              imports: [
                RouterModule.forRoot(
                  appRoutes,
                  { enableTracing: true } // <--debugging purposes only
                ),
                AppRoutingModule
              ],
              exports: [
                RouterModule
              ]
            })
            export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my angular-router-sample\src\app\app.module.ts:

```
                import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
            import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
            import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

            import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
            import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';



            import { CrisisListComponent } from './crisis-list/crisis-list.component';
            import { HeroListComponent } from './hero-list/hero-list.component';
            import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';


            @NgModule({
              declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                CrisisListComponent,
                HeroListComponent,
                PageNotFoundComponent
              ],
              imports: [
                BrowserModule,
                FormsModule,
                AppRoutingModule,
              //  AppRoutingModule


              ],
              providers: [],
              bootstrap: [AppComponent]
            })
            export class AppModule { }
```

This is my console log error:

[image: -]

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet (the app routing module), you have:

```
     imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ enableTracing: true }),
         AppRoutingModule]
})
```

Remove the `AppRoutingModule` from the import clause. As the error message suggests, the routing module can't import itself